# Cannot Find Function mvn

Tags: r, package, installation

I understand that when R says cannot find function, it is most likely a case of not loading the function from a package. In my case I downloaded the MVN package and the download binary packages could be found in

```
/var/folders/p1/m4807gq53cx77022wngjs4y00000gn/T//RtmpNothr8/downloaded_packages
```

Which I think is strange because it usually doesn't give me that output. Anyway I loaded the package with the `library()` function and no errors. So I proceduced with:

```
mard<-mvn(data=iris[1:50,1:4],mvnTest='mardia')
```

Then hit with the dreaded "Error, cannot find function "mvn."

I believe there is something wrong with where the package was downloaded, but I do not know the steps on how to fix it. I am using R version 3.1.2 for mac.

Comment: @G5W that is stated in the question.

Comment: What happens if you run `mard<-MVN::mvn(data=iris[1:50,1:4],mvnTest='mardia')`?

Comment: That did not work either, I had to update R itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, the MVN package requires R versions 3.5 and above. Since I had version, 3.1.2, it did not work. I had to update R.